# Django paginate for django 2

Tags: python, django

I need to use pagination to a Django list but I couldn't find any help online,, only old docs from Django version 1.3

here are my files :

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
    all_dress = Item.objects.all().filter(dress_active=True)
    all_good_dress = Item.objects.all().filter(dress_special=True)
    current_user = request.user
    context = {
        'all_dress': all_dress,
        'current_user': current_user,
        'all_good_dress':all_good_dress,
    }
    return render(request, 'fostania/home.html', context)
```

**Template(html)**

```
 {% for item in all_dress %}

        <div class="card border-info" style="width: 18rem;">
  <a href="{% url 'dress_details' item.pk%}"><img class="card-img-top" src="{{ item.dress_image1.url }}" alt="Card image cap"></a>
  <div class="card-body" align="right">
      <h5 class="card-title"><a href="{% url 'dress_details' item.pk%}">{{ item.dress_name }}</a>
          <br>{{ item.dress_action }}<br>{{ item.dress_price }} جنيه </h5>
    <p class="card-text">المقاس : {{ item.dress_size }}
    <br>{{ item.dress_city }}<br> {{ item.created_at|date:"SHORT_DATE_FORMAT" }}
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
        <br>
        <br>
                              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

      {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Have you read this Django 2 documentation?  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/pagination/

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how didn't I find this page,, it works great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the full doc and clear way to do it on this link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/pagination/

Answer (score 0):

import paginator in views.py

```
from django.core.paginator import EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger, Paginator
```

function:

```
def home(request):
all_dress = Item.objects.all().filter(dress_active=True)
all_good_dress = Item.objects.all().filter(dress_special=True)
current_user = request.user
paginator  = Paginator(all_dress, 10)
page = request.GET.get('page')

try: 
    all_dress = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    all_dress = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    all_dress = paginator.page(Paginator.num_pages)
context = {
    'all_dress': all_dress,
    'current_user': current_user,
    'all_good_dress':all_good_dress,
}
return render(request, 'fostania/home.html', context)
```

Template:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvTQS.png)

and one thing if user login you can direct acces his information in template like {{request.user.email}}