# Expandable Lists with Django

Tags: python, django

I'm currently developing a small web app with Django, where user can search for cards in a trading card game and the results shall be shown in a list. Since there could be quite a lot of results returned I thought of doing a dynamic list where only 50 items a time are shown and then the user can select the next 50 results via a button.

Is there a specific Django way of doing this?

This his how the page currently looks like (and I would prefer to have the button for the next results on the end of the page):

[image: example pic]

Comment: You can take a look at pagination: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/pagination/

Comment: As well as pagination from core Django as mentioned by @Landcross, I would throw a mention the way of [Django Tables2](https://github.com/jieter/django-tables2) which may be a little heavyweight if you just want to display the objects as a list, but has options for filtering, pagination, export etc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django paginate for django 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50449329/django-paginate-for-django-2)

Comment: @Landcross: Ah exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: @PyPingu: Interesting alternative to Landcross comment, thanks I'll have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

The comment from @Landcross (see first comment) was the solution I was looking for:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/pagination/

And @PyPingu posted an interesting alternative with 
https://github.com/jieter/django-tables2